# Raspberry Pi 3+ / 4 wifi connection problem

Tags: wifi, pi-4, pi-3b+

I am setting up the RPis 0W, 2, 3, 3+, and 4 for some tests. For the connection to the internet, I use WiFi. The setup worked as expected till the Pi 3+, which refused to connect to the router. Then I also checked the Pi 4 but same problem here.

For the setup, I am using the `2021-03-04-raspios-buster-armhf.img` from raspberrypi.org.

First I did the WiFi config manually, but to prevent possible errors from doing so, I only used raspi-config and always a fresh image. The following steps are done to setup wifi:

1. set locale : raspi-config > 5 ... > L1
2. set timezone : raspi-config > 5 ... > L2
3. set keyboard : raspi-config > 5 ... > L3
4. set wlan country : raspi-config > 5 ... > L4
5. set wlan credentials : raspi-config > 1 ... > S1
6. reboot

All Pis except the 3+ and 4 had the WiFi connection up and running after the reboot.

I checked the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` for the correct password and wlan-country and also compared them via `diff wpa_supplicant.conf.pi3 wpa_supplicant.conf.pi3p` with the result, that they are identical.

I did not modify the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

**wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
    ssid="FB7270"
    psk="<the password>"
}
```

**The output of `ip addr`**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:41:00:79 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:14:55:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**The output of `iwconfig`**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

**Scanning for available WiFi networks**

```
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
e8:df:70:df:ea:8e   2412    -73 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   ma*****
bc:05:43:8d:dc:dd   2412    -29 [WPA-PSK-TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS] FB7270
da:0d:17:55:13:ff   5520    -60 [ESS]   we*****
de:0d:17:55:13:ff   5520    -60 [ESS]   We*****
d8:0d:17:55:14:00   2432    -48 [MESH]  fr*****
da:0d:17:55:14:00   2432    -49 [ESS]   we*****
e0:28:6d:05:95:be   2412    -72 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   ma*****
e8:df:70:4d:ba:56   2462    -78 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   ma*****
d8:0d:17:55:13:ff   5520    -61 [MESH]  fr*****
de:0d:17:55:14:00   2432    -49 [ESS]   We*****
e8:df:70:4d:ba:57   5220    -87 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][WPS][ESS]   ma*****
```

The target wifi "FB7270" is visible.

**The content of syslog of Pi 3+ `cat /var/log/syslog | grep wlan0`**

```
Mar  4 23:04:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  4 23:04:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[433]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: dhcpcd_prestartinterface: wlan0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: dhcpcd_prestartinterface: wlan0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[444]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:09:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:09:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[423]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:09:24 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:09:24 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:18:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[464]: wlan0: removing interface
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[612]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:19:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[624]: wlan0: removing interface
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[668]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:29:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[680]: wlan0: removing interface
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[766]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:39:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:39:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[421]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:39:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:39:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:44:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:44:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[429]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:44:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:44:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `FB7270'
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi kernel: [   16.225662] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: IAID eb:14:55:2c
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: adding address fe80::53b6:caae:1d1d:9ec9
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[388]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::53b6:caae:1d1d:9ec9.
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[388]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[388]: Registering new address record for fe80::53b6:caae:1d1d:9ec9 on wlan0.*.
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Mar  5 00:44:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Mar  5 00:44:19 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: offered 192.168.0.103 from 192.168.0.1
Mar  5 00:44:19 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.0.103/24
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: leased 192.168.0.103 for 864000 seconds
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[388]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.103.
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[388]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[388]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.103 on wlan0.IPv4.
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
Mar  5 00:44:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[526]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
May 11 19:31:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 11 19:31:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[428]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 11 19:31:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
May 11 19:31:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
May 11 19:35:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 11 19:35:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[423]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 11 19:35:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
May 11 19:35:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
```

**The content of syslog of Pi 3+ `cat /var/log/syslog | grep dhcp`**

```
Mar  4 23:04:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  4 23:04:28 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: dev: loaded udev
Mar  4 23:04:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  4 23:04:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[433]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: dhcpcd_prestartinterface: wlan0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: dhcpcd_prestartinterface: wlan0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  4 23:05:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: timed out
Mar  4 23:05:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: timed out
Mar  4 23:05:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[349]: forked to background, child pid 506
Mar  4 23:05:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: dev: loaded udev
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[444]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:07:08 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:07:38 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: timed out
Mar  5 00:07:38 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: timed out
Mar  5 00:07:38 raspberrypi dhcpcd[362]: forked to background, child pid 627
Mar  5 00:07:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:09:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:09:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: dev: loaded udev
Mar  5 00:09:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:09:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[423]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:09:24 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:09:24 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:09:24 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:09:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: timed out
Mar  5 00:09:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: timed out
Mar  5 00:09:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[351]: forked to background, child pid 464
Mar  5 00:09:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:18:22 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:18:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[593]: sending signal TERM to pid 464
Mar  5 00:18:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[593]: waiting for pid 464 to exit
Mar  5 00:18:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[593]: sending signal TERM to pid 464
Mar  5 00:18:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[593]: waiting for pid 464 to exit
Mar  5 00:18:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[464]: received SIGTERM, stopping
Mar  5 00:18:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[464]: wlan0: removing interface
Mar  5 00:18:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[464]: eth0: removing interface
Mar  5 00:18:22 raspberrypi dhcpcd[464]: dhcpcd exited
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Succeeded.
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: dev: loaded udev
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[612]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:18:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:18:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: timed out
Mar  5 00:18:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: timed out
Mar  5 00:18:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[596]: forked to background, child pid 624
Mar  5 00:18:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:19:17 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:19:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[649]: sending signal TERM to pid 624
Mar  5 00:19:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[649]: waiting for pid 624 to exit
Mar  5 00:19:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[649]: sending signal TERM to pid 624
Mar  5 00:19:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[649]: waiting for pid 624 to exit
Mar  5 00:19:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[624]: received SIGTERM, stopping
Mar  5 00:19:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[624]: wlan0: removing interface
Mar  5 00:19:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[624]: eth0: removing interface
Mar  5 00:19:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[624]: dhcpcd exited
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Succeeded.
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: dev: loaded udev
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[668]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:19:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:19:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: timed out
Mar  5 00:19:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: timed out
Mar  5 00:19:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[652]: forked to background, child pid 680
Mar  5 00:19:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:29:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:29:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[744]: sending signal TERM to pid 680
Mar  5 00:29:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[744]: waiting for pid 680 to exit
Mar  5 00:29:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[744]: sending signal TERM to pid 680
Mar  5 00:29:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[744]: waiting for pid 680 to exit
Mar  5 00:29:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[680]: received SIGTERM, stopping
Mar  5 00:29:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[680]: wlan0: removing interface
Mar  5 00:29:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[680]: eth0: removing interface
Mar  5 00:29:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[680]: dhcpcd exited
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Succeeded.
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: dev: loaded udev
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[766]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:29:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:29:45 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: timed out
Mar  5 00:29:45 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: timed out
Mar  5 00:29:45 raspberrypi dhcpcd[750]: forked to background, child pid 778
Mar  5 00:29:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:39:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:39:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: dev: loaded udev
Mar  5 00:39:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:39:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[421]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:39:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:39:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:39:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:40:20 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: timed out
Mar  5 00:40:20 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: timed out
Mar  5 00:40:20 raspberrypi dhcpcd[347]: forked to background, child pid 466
Mar  5 00:40:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:44:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:44:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: dev: loaded udev
Mar  5 00:44:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:44:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[429]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:44:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:44:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:44:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `FB7270'
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: DUID 00:01:00:01:27:d4:2d:51:b8:27:eb:14:55:2c
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: IAID eb:14:55:2c
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: adding address fe80::53b6:caae:1d1d:9ec9
Mar  5 00:44:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Mar  5 00:44:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Mar  5 00:44:19 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: offered 192.168.0.103 from 192.168.0.1
Mar  5 00:44:19 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.0.103/24
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: leased 192.168.0.103 for 864000 seconds
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: Too few arguments.
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: Too few arguments.
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: Failed to get unit file state for ntp.service: No such file or directory
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: forked to background, child pid 526
Mar  5 00:44:25 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:44:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[526]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
May 11 19:31:49 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
May 11 19:31:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: dev: loaded udev
May 11 19:31:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 11 19:31:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[428]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 11 19:31:49 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
May 11 19:31:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: waiting for carrier
May 11 19:31:50 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
May 11 19:32:20 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: timed out
May 11 19:32:20 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: timed out
May 11 19:32:20 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: forked to background, child pid 472
May 11 19:32:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
May 11 19:35:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
May 11 19:35:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: dev: loaded udev
May 11 19:35:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 11 19:35:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[423]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
May 11 19:35:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
May 11 19:35:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: eth0: waiting for carrier
May 11 19:35:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
May 11 19:36:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: timed out
May 11 19:36:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: timed out
May 11 19:36:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[395]: forked to background, child pid 463
May 11 19:36:02 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
```

**The content of syslog of Pi 3 `cat /var/log/syslog | grep dhcp`**

```
Mar  4 23:04:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  4 23:04:28 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: dev: loaded udev
Mar  4 23:04:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  4 23:04:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[452]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: dhcpcd_prestartinterface: wlan0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: dhcpcd_prestartinterface: wlan0: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Mar  4 23:04:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  4 23:05:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: timed out
Mar  4 23:05:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: timed out
Mar  4 23:05:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[385]: forked to background, child pid 530
Mar  4 23:05:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  4 23:08:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[530]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Mar  4 23:08:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[530]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `FB7270'
Mar  4 23:08:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[530]: DUID 00:01:00:01:27:d4:24:df:b8:27:eb:d5:9e:8b
Mar  4 23:08:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[530]: wlan0: IAID eb:d5:9e:8b
Mar  4 23:08:15 raspberrypi dhcpcd[530]: wlan0: adding address fe80::7862:751e:3fa2:6913
Mar  4 23:08:16 raspberrypi dhcpcd[530]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Mar  4 23:08:16 raspberrypi dhcpcd[530]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Mar  4 23:08:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[530]: wlan0: offered 192.168.0.102 from 192.168.0.1
Mar  4 23:08:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[530]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.0.102/24
Mar  5 00:08:24 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Mar  5 00:08:24 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: dev: loaded udev
Mar  5 00:08:24 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:08:24 raspberrypi dhcpcd-run-hooks[460]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Mar  5 00:08:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Mar  5 00:08:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:08:25 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Mar  5 00:08:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Mar  5 00:08:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `FB7270'
Mar  5 00:08:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: DUID 00:01:00:01:27:d4:24:df:b8:27:eb:d5:9e:8b
Mar  5 00:08:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: IAID eb:d5:9e:8b
Mar  5 00:08:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: adding address fe80::7862:751e:3fa2:6913
Mar  5 00:08:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Mar  5 00:08:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Mar  5 00:08:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: offered 192.168.0.102 from 192.168.0.1
Mar  5 00:08:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.0.102/24
Mar  5 00:08:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: leased 192.168.0.102 for 864000 seconds
Mar  5 00:08:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
Mar  5 00:08:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
Mar  5 00:08:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: Too few arguments.
Mar  5 00:08:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: Too few arguments.
Mar  5 00:08:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: Failed to get unit file state for ntp.service: No such file or directory
Mar  5 00:08:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[368]: forked to background, child pid 699
Mar  5 00:08:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Mar  5 00:08:39 raspberrypi dhcpcd[699]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

By comparing the syslogs of the Pi 3 and 3+ one can see that the 3+ (and the same for the 4) get stuck on `wlan0: waiting for carrier`.

**check of running processes `ps -aux | grep -i wpa`**

```
root       373  0.0  0.3  10744  3752 ?        Ss   19:35   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
root       427  0.0  0.4  11116  4160 ?        Ss   19:35   0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
pi         605  0.0  0.0   7360   512 tty1     S+   19:44   0:00 grep --color=auto -i wpa
```

For me, it seems like the wpa_supplicant is running.

**miscellaneous**

I also tried another router to check if the problem is router-related, but this did not change the problem.

The Raspberries are approximately 50cm away from the router.

I am not new to Linux and Raspberry Pi, but because I never had such problems with networking, I have no ideas left where to search for the problem.

Could you please help in finding the problem?

Comment: out of interest, do you have a 5GHz access point you can try to connect to ... the 3b+ and 4 are dual band - odd, I think you're the 4th person in about a week that is using DE country code to have issues (coincidence?) Also, this may sound stupid, but if you connect ethernet to the router, does the wifi suddenly work (that's what a couple of others have reported)

Comment: @JaromandaX Unfortunately, I only have 2.4GHz routers. I tried connecting the ethernet cable to the Pi, but this did not change the problem. Even after some reboots, the wlan0 interface does not get an IP address.